# Building an array, containing multiple values in single quotes while separating each with commas

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'd like my end result to look something like:

```
Vendor1 => 'description1,description2,description3',
Vendor2 => 'description4,description5,description6'
```

I currently have something like this:

```
if(mssql_num_rows($execute)){
   while($row = mssql_fetch_array($execute)){
        $dropdown[$row['VendorName']] .=  "'" . $row['Transaction Description'] . "',";
   }
}
```

But this gives me:

```
["Harland Financial Solutions"]=>
  string(54) "'Software-implemention/license/support','sfw support',"
```

Comment: Is that not what you have there? Are you referring to how `$dropdown` is printed? If so, you need to show us what code you are using to print out its values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can just remove the trailing comma and remove the single quotes.

```
if(mssql_num_rows($execute)){
   while($row = mssql_fetch_array($execute)){
        $dropdown[$row['VendorName']] .= $row['Transaction Description'].","
   }
   foreach($dropdown as $vendor => &$descriptions)
       $descriptions = substr($descriptions, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: $descriptions != $description

Comment: spot on. sorry, sleep deprived. fixed. And goodnight!

Comment: Now you have my vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the while loop, use the php function `$string = substr($string, 0, -1)`. It will return a string that is one character shorter than the original (if you fill in the example correctly). The result is a string with the last comma chopped of the end. Documentation on `substr()` can be found in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
if(...){
   while(...){
      ...
      foreach($dropdown as &$string)
         $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
   }
}
```

Comment: if i understand/imagine his data correctly, he'll need to loop over possible vendor values w/ foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
.
.
.
 $dropdown[$row['VendorName']] .=  $row['Transaction Description'] . ",";
.
.
.
```

the you can do smth like

```
foreach ($dropdown as $vendor=>&$data)
$data=mb_substr($data,0,-1);//to remove the last , that you don't need
```

Comment: foreach ($dropdown as $vendor=>&$data) //note the reference (&)

Comment: forgot the reference :)